# Dplyr a function and refactoring a column

Tags: r, function, dplyr

Having problems with quoting and unquoting variable names within an R function that uses dplyr.  Have been through this site as well as Hadley's [Programming with dplyr](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) site and it's still getting the best of me.

The function code that **doesn't work** is:

```
gcreatedata <- function(dataframe,depvar,iv1,iv2){
  depvar <- enquo(depvar)
  iv1 <- enquo(iv1)
  iv2 <- enquo(iv2)
  newdata <- dataframe %>%
    mutate(!!iv1 := factor(!!iv1)) %>%
    group_by(!!iv1, !!iv2)  %>%
    summarise(TheMean = mean(!!depvar,na.rm=TRUE),
          TheSD = sd(!!depvar,na.rm=TRUE),
          TheSEM = sd(!!depvar,na.rm=TRUE)/sqrt(length(!!depvar)),
          CI95Muliplier = qt(.95/2 + .5, length(!!depvar)-1))
return(as_tibble(newdata))
}
```

calling it with `mtcars` it would be

```
sss <- gcreatedata(mtcars,mpg,am,cyl)
```

I'm simply trying to convert the variable `am` to a factor for use downstream in a ggplot.  Yes I know I could do it before I enter the function but I want it generic.  The function works minus the factor step just fine which you can see if you run this version.

```
gcreatedata <- function(dataframe,depvar,iv1,iv2){
  depvar <- enquo(depvar)
  iv1 <- enquo(iv1)
  iv2 <- enquo(iv2)
  newdata <- dataframe %>%
    mutate(foo := factor(!!iv1)) %>%
    group_by(foo, !!iv2)  %>%
    summarise(TheMean = mean(!!depvar,na.rm=TRUE),
          TheSD = sd(!!depvar,na.rm=TRUE),
          TheSEM = sd(!!depvar,na.rm=TRUE)/sqrt(length(!!depvar)),
          CI95Muliplier = qt(.95/2 + .5, length(!!depvar)-1))
  return(as_tibble(newdata))
}
sss <- gcreatedata(mtcars,mpg,am,cyl)
```

It returns what I want except for the fact that `am` has become `foo` how do I get the name right in this line of code `mutate(!!iv1 := factor(!!iv1)) %>%` right now I'm getting an `Error: LHS must be a name or string` message and despite all manner of combinations I could think of no dice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well 24 hours brought me a clearer head.  Here's the answer should anyone else need it in the future...

```
gcreatedata <- function(dataframe,depvar,iv1,iv2){
  depvar <- enquo(depvar)
  iv1 <- enquo(iv1)
  iv2 <- enquo(iv2)
  newdata <- dataframe %>%
    mutate(!!quo_name(iv1) := factor(!!iv1), !!quo_name(iv2) := factor(!!iv2)) %>%
    group_by(!!iv1, !!iv2)  %>%
    summarise(TheMean = mean(!!depvar,na.rm=TRUE),
              TheSD = sd(!!depvar,na.rm=TRUE),
              TheSEM = sd(!!depvar,na.rm=TRUE)/sqrt(length(!!depvar)),
              CI95Muliplier = qt(.95/2 + .5, length(!!depvar)-1))
  return(as_tibble(newdata))
}
```

to test it on common data...

```
gcreatedata(mtcars,mpg,am,vs)
# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Groups:   am [?]
  am    vs    TheMean TheSD TheSEM CI95Muliplier
  <fct> <fct>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>         <dbl>
1 0     0        15.0  2.77  0.801          2.20
2 0     1        20.7  2.47  0.934          2.45
3 1     0        19.8  4.01  1.64           2.57
4 1     1        28.4  4.76  1.80           2.45
```

Answer (score 1):

Your situation is described in the tutorial part here: http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#different-input-and-output-variable

The following code works for me:

```
> library(dplyr)
> 
> gcreatedata <- function(dataframe,depvar,iv1,iv2){
+   depvar <- enquo(depvar)
+   iv1_q <- enquo(iv1)
+   iv2 <- enquo(iv2)
+   
+   iv1_name <- paste0("mean_", quo_name(iv1_q))
+   
+   newdata <- dataframe %>%
+     mutate(!!iv1_name := factor(!!iv1_q)) %>%
+     group_by(!!iv1_q, !!iv2)  %>%
+     summarise(TheMean = mean(!!depvar,na.rm=TRUE),
+               TheSD = sd(!!depvar,na.rm=TRUE),
+               TheSEM = sd(!!depvar,na.rm=TRUE)/sqrt(length(!!depvar)),
+               CI95Muliplier = qt(.95/2 + .5, length(!!depvar)-1))
+   return(as_tibble(newdata))
+ }
> sss <- gcreatedata(mtcars,mpg,am,cyl)
> sss
# A tibble: 6 x 6
# Groups:   am [?]
     am   cyl TheMean TheSD TheSEM CI95Muliplier
  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>         <dbl>
1  0     4.00    22.9 1.45   0.839          4.30
2  0     6.00    19.1 1.63   0.816          3.18
3  0     8.00    15.0 2.77   0.801          2.20
4  1.00  4.00    28.1 4.48   1.59           2.36
5  1.00  6.00    20.6 0.751  0.433          4.30
6  1.00  8.00    15.4 0.566  0.400         12.7
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @sastibe yes I saw that but was hoping to avoid the dodge of having to create a new column name variable just to have to stiuck it right back in an existing column name.  Thanks though I will definitely keep in mind if I can't find a cleaner solution.  Chuck